# Adding live data to Highchart Timeline

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to create a timeline graph to show events over time using Highchart. I've been able to create a static graph (events in last 15 mins), but not able to add live events to it (every minute). I'm using the standalone method (vanilla js).

createTimeline() method will get called at page load. all_events is obtained via an ajax call to the backend server.

I've added chart.events.load to fetch live events after page load and trigger it at every 1 minute.

```
function createTimeline() {
    data = []
    // Creating data I need to add at load time
    for(var event of all_events['events_15m']) {
        obj = {
            'x': Date.parse(event.event_time['$date']),
            'name': event.source + ' ' + event.event_name,
            'label': event.event_name,
            'description': 'User:' + event.user + ' \nApplication: ' + event.application + ' ' + JSON.stringify(event.details)
        }
        data.push(obj)
    }
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false
        }
    });
    timelineChart = Highcharts.chart('timelineChart', {
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'name',
            type: 'timeline',
            events : {
                load : function () {
                    // call this at every minute
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    
                    setInterval(function () {
                        console.log(series)
                        events_1m = []
                        var start_time = moment().subtract(1, 'minutes').format('MM/D/YYYY HH:mm A');
                        payload = JSON.stringify({
                            time_gte: start_time
                        })
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/filter",
                            data: payload,
                            contentType: "application/json",
                            success: function(d) {
                                events_1m = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(d));
                                for(var event of events_1m) {
                                    obj = {
                                        dataLabels: {
                                            allowOverlap: false,
                                            format: '<span style="color:{point.color}">● </span><span style="font-weight: bold;" > ' +
                                                '{point.x:%H:%M:%S}</span><br/>{point.label}'
                                        },
                                        marker: {
                                            symbol: 'circle'
                                        },
                                        data: {
                                            'x': Date.parse(event.event_time['$date']),
                                            'name': event.source + ' ' + event.event_name,
                                            'label': event.event_name,
                                            'description': 'User:' + event.user + ' \nApplication: ' + event.application + ' ' + JSON.stringify(event.details)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                series.addPoint([obj], true, true);
                            }
                        });
                    }, 60000);
                }
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            visible: true,
        },
        yAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            title: null,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Timeline of Events (last 15 mins)'
        },
        tooltip: {
            style: {
                width: 300
            }
        },
        series: [{
            dataLabels: {
                allowOverlap: false,
                format: '<span style="color:{point.color}">● </span><span style="font-weight: bold;" > ' +
                    '{point.x:%H:%M:%S}</span><br/>{point.label}'
            },
            marker: {
                symbol: 'circle'
            },
            data: data
        }],
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                turboThreshold: 10000
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Events fetched at the load time are displayed correctly on the graph, but newer events are not appended. setInterval calls the method successfully at every 1 min, I validated this by adding console.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the point as an object, not an array with a single object.

```
series.addPoint(obj);
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wn306vhc/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint

Comment: Thank you so much!
Another thing that I was doing was that I wasn't getting the correct values for Date.parse in setInterval (data.x); fixing that helped fix the issue for good.

Another thing that I am stuck with – I want last 15 mins datapoints to always be visible, but whenever there is a time gap between datapoints, I lose few minutes. Any idea how to retain that?

Comment: Hi @Anchal Chaudhary, You can use `setExtremes` method to adapt x-axis. Also, please remember to set the second argument of the `addPoint` method to `false` to avoid redrawing the chart twice. Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v9yghxq4/